# php mysql combine queries

Tags: php, mysql

If I have 2 mysql_query commands in a single php file, is their a way to combine them?

For example, I have:

```
$a=mysql_query(SELECT * FROM table1);
$b=mysql_query(SELECT id FROM table3);
```

but I want to combine them into a single mysql_query, would this be more efficient? would it be faster?

Comment: Is there any relationship between table1 and table3?

Comment: If they are not related to each other, e.g. you only want those elements from table1 which id is also in table3, then there is no point in combining them. They are doing different things. So the question is: What are you doing with the results?

Comment: what exactly do you mean about "combine"? (joining or union)

Comment: There is no relationship between the 2 tables.  Sorry, my explanation was not very good, I mean combine as in the php code, like can I use a single mysql_query to run both mysql queries?  like mysql_query(firstone;secondone); or something...hope that makes sense!

Comment: Please stop posting here Col. Shrapnel.  Your negativity is not wanted here anymore.  Go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple queries are not supported in mysql_query as descripted on [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), so you can't combine both query in php mysql_query way
Here is another good reference from [php manual notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#91669):

> Executed with multiple queries at
>   once, the mysql_query function will
>   return a result only for the first
>   query. The other queries will be
>   executed as well, but you won't have a
>   result for them.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` should work ([MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/union.html))

```
SELECT id FROM table1 UNION SELECT id FROM table3;
```

Edit:
I see: You want all ("*") from table1. This is a little bit more difficult, but `UNION` may help also. However, you are really sure you want to do this? Is there any relationship beetween those two tables, or should this just be a kind of micro optimization?

Comment: There is no relationship between the 2 tables. Sorry, my explanation was not very good, I mean combine as in the php code, like can I use a single mysql_query to run both mysql queries? like mysql_query(firstone;secondone); or something...hope that makes sense!